# currently selected tab of ttk::notebook

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

I've created a window with menu and two notebook tabs. In the menu I have a button "Open" and it's opening me a file aaa.txt in a text widget in notebook tab 1. The problem is that I would like to open it not in tab 1 but in current selected/displayed/active notebook tab (could be tab 1 or tab 2). Code below:

```
proc CommandOpen { } {
    set f [open aaa.txt r]
    set x [read $f]
    .f.nb.f1.f11.t1 insert 1.0 $x
    close $f
}

wm title .  
wm geometry . 640x460  
pack [frame .f] -fill both  
pack [ttk::notebook .f.nb] -fill both  
.f.nb add [frame .f.nb.f1] -text "tab1"   
pack [frame .f.nb.f1.f11] -side top -fill both  
pack [text .f.nb.f1.f11.t1 -bg white] -side left -fill both  
.f.nb add [frame .f.nb.f2] -text "tab2"  
pack [text .f.nb.f2.t1 -bg white] -side left -fill both    
menu .mbar -borderwidth 1   
. configure -menu .mbar    
.mbar add cascade -label "File" -underline 0 -menu [menu .mbar.file -tearoff 0]  
set mf .mbar.file  
$mf add command -label "Open" -command CommandOpen -underline 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the currently selected tab index using:

```
.f.nb index current
```

This is [documented on the manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm) (it's the **index** method and the **current** *tabid*).

---

To get the slave widget which is managed by a particular tab, you index into the results of the **tabs** method. Overall, you get:

```
set currentSubwindow [lindex [.f.nb tabs] [.f.nb index current]]
```

Comment: ok, but how can I use it in my procedure CommandOpen to open a file in current text widget?

Comment: @lucas That should do it. (It's not _quite_ as obvious as I think it ought to be, but I didn't write this code and I'm very glad someone else did.)

Comment: ok, and now when I have this variable currentSubwindow? I have to create a statement in my proc CommandOpen using this variable which will put content of aaa.txt to text widget .f.nb.f1.f11.t1 or .f.nb.f2 ?

Comment: @lucas You know what widget it is; just use it. Maybe with `$currentSubwindow.f11.t1`. What you do with the widget name is _your_ business.

Comment: @lucas These names sure can be confusing, and even more so if you're not the one who made those up!